# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client

Tags: android, jersey

```
03-13 08:10:19.621: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
```

Why im getting this exception?Though i have added jars.

Comment: have you added jar files as Library ?

Comment: is the jar added to your `'libs/` did you add it to your build path?

Answer (score 1):

Add the used libraries in your application manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="your library" />
```

**Edit:**

btw. make sure that you have added **jersey-core** to your classpath too, as it is a dependency for com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.

Comment: What value i must give for android:name.

Comment: The name of your library, I suppose "com.sun.jersey"

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1. Remove all references to the JAR in your project from `Java project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries`
2. Create a `libs` folder if not exist at the root of your project `Copy` the JAR into the `libs` folder.
3. If still not running . Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

`clean your project` and run. it will work

Comment: what's your problem now.is it same or any other

Comment: When I'm following above steps. I'm getting below error [2013-03-13 14:08:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sun/jersey/core/util/MultivaluedMapImpl; [2013-03-13 14:08:57 - DictionaryApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sun/jersey/core/util/MultivaluedMapImpl;

Comment: actually if your facing problem with jar files this solution will solve your problem, but your error is not relating to that. show me which line causes error in your code.

Comment: I got to know that jersey is a heavy weight for android so i shifted to HttpClient to make a web service but now i get INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error.

Comment: are you using any google maps in your applivcation, if yes are you using google map support emulator to run the application..

Comment: Nope.I resolved that issue.Im trying to hit WordNik webservice and now im getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. you have to run code related to web in AsyncTask...http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/964741

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have added jar files into project but haven't added them as Library, just follow these steps,

- Right Click on your project, select "Build Path"
- From Build Path select "Configure Build Path"
- Select "Library" Tab from the dialog
- Click on first button "Add Jars"
- Select jar files from your Project folder
- Clean the project and done.

Comment: When I'm following above steps. I'm getting below error                  [2013-03-13 14:08:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sun/jersey/core/util/MultivaluedMapImpl;
[2013-03-13 14:08:57 - DictionaryApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sun/jersey/core/util/MultivaluedMapImpl;

Comment: in which folder of your project you have put your .jar files ?